# typescript and angular accessing service instance in a static method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service which fetches the data object from the server. There is another class which is a general utility class. It has a static method in which i want to use service instance. but due to method being static this wont work. example code:

```
export class DataUtil {
    constructor(public core:CoreStructureService){

    }

    static fetchContact(id:string):ContactModel{
        for(let contact of this.core.contactList){
        if(contact.contactId == id)
            return contact
        }
    }

}
```

This will not compile as the line this.core.contactList in the for stmt is not valid. being method static i cannot refer core as this.core. 
So how do i fix this.

Comment: Why is `fetchContact` static?

Comment: because it is a generic method i need to use frequently. i do not want to instantaniate the class everytime i need to search contact matching the id.

Comment: This is not a `generic` method per se. It's a generalized method probably.

Comment: sure but that i see a fairly common usecase for me

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of the reputation I'm posting this as an answer.

Do NOT access `core` service methods from a `static` method. This is just bad. And this is exactly why the compiler is slapping you.

---

**Have your `fetchContact` method an instance method instead of static.**

```
export class DataUtil {
    constructor(public core:CoreStructureService){

    }

    fetchContact(id:string):ContactModel{
        for(let contact of this.core.contactList){
        if(contact.contactId == id)
            return contact
        }
    }

}
```

---

But... yes, you *could* work around it in a very dirty, half-working way. I am intentionally not going to describe it.

But, but, but... No, you're trying to do a bad thing.

Comment: how do u gonna do that if the object contactList is in the service ?

Comment: @Vik get rid of the `static` and do inject `DataUtil` as an instance wherever you need it. Please stop using `static` classes where we can easily avoid them. It will make everyone's life better. More readable code, more testable code, etc.

Comment: here is a problem with that.   so if i make it a service instead and start injecting so my another class which create object and need this would need to inject it as well in the constructor. 

as a result the constructor becomes constructor(sv1:DataUtil, val1, va2)

now  where ever i create the object of above call that would also require me to pass this injected param. this does not look right

Comment: `now where ever i create the object of above call that would also require me to pass this injected param.` This is totally all right. This actually tells you that you have a dependency you were not thinking well enough. It also says you are trying to construct something by hand which you're not supposed to do if you have a DI container set up

Comment: what do u mean by settng up a DI container?

Comment: @Vik please refer to Angular documentation. It comes enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

If `DataUtil` was a service injected by Angular, it would not be destroyed until the corresponding injector is destroyed. I doubt you will have performance problems because of class instantiation. Try it with a regular service and only come back to this problem, if you really do have performance issues.

For further information, have a look at the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).